# Can we use past forms in a sentence with "now"?

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

> Now that I have finished my work, I can finally have my lunch.

Can -ed be used in the same sentence as ’now’?

Answer (score 2):

The verb you picked out, "have finished", is in the present perfect tense (have + past participle).

We can use the present perfect with "now" to indicate the current status of a process begun in the past.

> I've done my homework now

The **current status** of *my homework* is *done*. Some time before now, the homework was done.

In your sentence, the current status of work (the status of work right now) is *finished*, so now the speaker is free to have lunch (which explains why *now* is of interest).